# Implementing FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON by using SharedPreferences for an Activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to make my screen always on. This will be applied for MainActivity.java that using this code:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Here's my code:

**xml\preferences.xml**

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="prefKeepScreenOn"
        android:title="@string/prefs_screen_on"
        android:summary="@string/summ_screen_on"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // By using SharedPreferences,
                                            // this screen should never turned off.
}
```

As you can see, I have a CheckBoxPreference that has defaultValue="false". When the value changed to "true" or the CheckBoxPreference is checked, the screen will never turned off and using this code: *getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);*

I've tried to search the tutorials about SharedPreferences in Google, but I didn't found anything to implement it. I do not understand with SharedPreferences, because I'm a Newbie.
I am very grateful to anyone who wants to help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this in your Activity.

```
    SharedPreferences myPreference=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

   if(myPreference.getBoolean("prefKeepScreenOn", false)) {

       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
```